# How can I do the same thing without using "go to"

Tags: c

Hi I typed that code a few weeks ago but the teacher's response: "
Do the same thing without using go to "

So I don't know whether I can do the same thing without using "go to". Is there any simple but effective way like "go to" function?

> So what can I do about that?

https://github.com/MuzaffeerD/Login/blob/main/finalform.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int main() {
  static
  const char PSWRD[] = "1234";
  char p[6];
  int n = 3, y;
  int islem;
  int bakiye = 100;
  int tutar;

  printf("Welcome");

  do {
    printf("\n\nStudent_ID:Elif");
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("\nPassword:");
    scanf("%s", p);
    fflush(stdout);

    y = strcmp(p, PSWRD);

    if (y == 0) {
      printf("\nSucessfull Login\n"); //succesfull login
      goto islemler;
    } else {
      n--;
      printf("\nWrong password, try again: "); //wrong password try again
      printf("\nRemaining attempts  ");
      printf("%d\n", n);
      getchar();
    }

    if (n < 1) {
      printf("\nYour account has been blocked\n");
      return 0;
    }
  } while (n > 0);
  islemler:
    printf("Islemler\nPara yatirmak icin 1 \nPara cekmek icin 2\nHesap bakiyenizi gormek icin 3\nCikmak icin 4 girimiz");
  do {

    printf("\n\nIslem Seciniz:");
    scanf("%d", & islem); {

      switch (islem) {

      case 1:
        printf("Bakiyeniz %d \n", bakiye);
        printf("\nYatirilacak Tutar:");
        scanf("%d", & tutar);
        bakiye += tutar;
        printf("Bakiyeniz: %d", bakiye);
        break;

      case 2:
        printf("Bakiyeniz %d \n", bakiye);
        printf("\nCekilecek Tutar:");
        scanf("%d", & tutar);
        if (tutar > bakiye) {
          printf("Bakiye yetersiz\n");
        }
        bakiye -= tutar;
        printf("Bakiyeniz: %d", bakiye);
        break;

      case 3:
        printf("Bakiyeniz: %d", bakiye);
        break;

      case 4:
        printf("Cikis Yapiliyor");
        return 0;

      default:
        printf("Hatali Islem");
        return 0;
      }
    }
  } while (islem);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `break`.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the code that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the repository you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `break` statements causes program control to leave the loop the `break` is in and continue just beyond the end of the loop. So this code:

```
do
{
   …
   if (something)
       goto beyondloop;
   …
} while (something);
beyondloop:
```

is equivalent to:

```
do
{
   …
   if (something)
       break;
   …
} while (something);
```

provided the `break` statement is not inside a loop embedded in that loop or inside a `switch` statement.